# In Vue client and server application how to eliminate the need for CORS?

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, cors, axios

I am following MEVN stack based tutorial here:

[MEVN Stack Tutorial](https://medium.com/@anaida07/mevn-stack-application-part-1-3a27b61dcae0)

Its a blog post app, client is Vue based SPA (lets call it app A) and backend is express based which provides Mongo data with JSON Rest based API (lets call it app B. However, it is using cors package in B to allow cross origin requests which is a security risk allowing third party to directly make call to app B APIs.

How can I eliminate the need for CORS in app B? I am looking for correct approach. One is app A browser Javascript does not make calls to app B but makes calls to app A backend by adding express package in app A which in turn makes same call ( after checking validity of request parameters) to app B. But in this case where express based app.js lives in Vue directory structure of app A?

I am using axios for http in app A and I am not sure how that can be used to solve above problem.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think CORS is a security risk? CORS is commonly used in all kinds of applications and it is not a security risk if used correctly. You can choose which origins and methods are allowed with CORS.

The only reasonable way to eliminate CORS is to host both applications on the same domain. That way the requests are not Cross Origin anymore as the applications share their origin.